# How to recell a 60 cell 36V battery pack?

Tags: batteries, diy

So unfortunately a disgruntled ex-housemate put a screw through my friend's electric bike battery pack.
It has burst one cell so we're definitely not plugging it in.
I think I'm capable of replacing it however I'm a bit stumped when it comes to identifying the cell rating of the cells currently in there. Ideally I wouldn't replace all of them (60 cells!) but only the 3 cells that are connected in series.
I've checked rs components which seem to have the batteries which I could solder in.
Would replacing just the 3 of them be a viable fix? Any advice is really appreciated

Comment: Welcome! If it has a BMS it may lock out forever if you remove voltage of one cell measurement. If the cell is burst, it could already have happened.

Comment: Are the cells marked at all?  A photo might help.

Comment: In some cases, mixing new cells with old cells may speed up the demise of all the cells. Do you know if the BMS has cell balancing?

Comment: I assume it's a LiPo or other Li-ion?

Comment: Lion, completely missed that important piece of info

Comment: @winny thank you! Ah yes I have heard about that. Knowing this, would it just be best to get a new battery pack to install into the case?

Comment: @rdtsc not marked at all hence its tricky to find a direct replacement for the cells effected

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy not a clue, I suspect its just a cheap pack so perhaps not

Comment: Replacing cells are not for the faint hearted as there are many dangers and you need a spot welder. There are commercial services which will do the job but without knowing the details on the BMS, is a risk you’ll end up with a useless pack even after replacing defective cells.